# Setting value based on another column in dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
A  P(A)
1  0.8
0  0.7
1  0.5
1  0.8
1  0.9
0  0.7
0  0.8
```

For all 0's in column `A`, I would like to calculate `1-P(A)`. This would give me the following dataset:

```
A  P(A)
1  0.8
0  0.3  ## 1 - 0.7
1  0.5
1  0.8
1  0.9
0  0.3  ## 1 - 0.7
0  0.2  ## 1 - 0.8
```

I tried this but it doesn't give me the required output.

```
  for(i in nrow(results)) {
    if(results[i,1]==0) {
      results[i,2]<- 1-results[i,2] 
    }
  }
```

How is this possible in R?

Comment: Do you want those values as another column in the same data frame? And you want the result of the calculation, right, not an equation for it?

Comment: Just `df[df$A == 0, 2] <- 1 - df[df$A == 0, 2]` This is very basic operation in R. You really need to read some tutorials.

Comment: `with(DF, \`P(A)\`^A*(1-\`P(A)\`)^(1-A))` similar to any other programming language... As you can see, `P(A)` is a bad name for a column... There's also `dbinom(DF$A, size=1, prob=DF$\`P(A)\`)`

Comment: I want it stored in the same column P(A).

Comment: @DavidArenburg - I'm a Java programmer trying to learn R.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0), P = c(0.8, 0.7, 0.5,0.8, 0.9,0.7,0.8))

df[df$A == 0, "P" ] <- 1 - df[df$A == 0, "P"]
```

Comment: @Frank just fixed it.  That is what I get for not testing it first.